# Android - Setting up Toolbar for Multiple Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I have an `Activity` which has a `Fragment` container for almost all fragments in my app. In some `Fragment`, the toolbar needs changes such as title, image, home button.. Here's the code of the toolbar in the Activity :

```
@Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.clear();
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_toolbar_top, menu);
        boolean drawerOpen = drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(navigationView);
        searchBtnMenu = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_toolbar_top_menu_searchBtn);
        messageMenu = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_toolbar_top_menu_message);
        searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchBtnMenu);
        searchView.setQuery("", true);
        drawerMenu = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_toolbar_top_menu_drawer);

    ImageView searchClose = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_close_btn);
    searchClose.setColorFilter(
            NewsfeedActivity.this.getResources().getColor(R.color.white),
            android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
....
```

I have overridden back button and back on `Toolbar` (home) to pop backstack.

There are several solution I've thought of :

1. Setting everything inside the Activity. Whenever a `Fragment` needs to be replaced, I check the `Fragment`'s tag and switch the `Toolbar` to that certain `Fragment` `Toolbar`
2. Overriding `onPrepareOptionsMenu` in every Fragment where needed. When backstack is popped, the activity has a method to check which `Fragment` is before it, and have the `Toolbar` set up for that `Fragment`
3. Having like.. 10 or more `Toolbars` with visibility `GONE` and make them visible whenever they are needed.

Point number 3 is.. Last resort.. And I'm not sure with the performance either.

So.. Any suggestion on what to do here?

And please tell me if I forgot to add any detail :D

Update :

4. Simply adding toolbar to every `Fragment`. So I have n number of `Toolbar` where n is number of `Fragment`..

Comment: Hi @kevin what worked for you??

Comment: @rakeshkashyap In the end, because it sucks to have different toolbars for each Fragment due to layout calculations and stuffs, I just use 1 toolbar which is in the activity above `FrameLayout` and have a function to change title and icon from the `Fragment` like `((MainActivity)getActivity).changeToolbarProperties(R.drawable.lalala, "Title");`

Comment: thanks for the pointers

Comment: @rakeshkashyap You're very welcome! :D You can ask me anytime bro